# return a string value in flutter sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, flutter, select

**i want to get username String value for the specific deviceId from database but i am getting this error**

`UserName===Instance of 'Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>`

I can insert data  successfully in table, only the problem in returning the value.

here is my code:

declaring database and columns:

```
static final _databaseName = "MyDatabase.db";
  static final _databaseVersion = 1;

  static final table = 'my_table';

  static final columnId = '_id';
  static final columnName = 'name';
  static final columnPassword = 'password';
  static final columnDeviceID = 'deviceID';

///....
////...

Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE $table (
            $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            $columnName STRING NOT NULL,
            $columnPassword STRING NOT NULL,
            $columnDeviceID STRING NOT NULL UNIQUE
          )
          ''');
  }
```

get Name method

```
Future<String> getName(String deviceid) async{
    Database db = await instance.database;
   String name= await columnName;
  db.rawQuery('SELECT $name FROM $table WHERE $columnDeviceID = $deviceid');
   return name;
  }
```

and here is how am using **getName** method in app to get the value:

`String user_name = await dbHelper.getName(deviceId);`

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(unrecognized token: "8d4eldkfjdfl58" (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE deviceID = 8d4eldkfjdfl58, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)) sql 'SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE deviceID = 8d4eldkfjdfl58' args []}

Comment: Try to add `deviceId` to double quotes in `where` and parse database result manually after receiving it.

Comment: thank you for response but getting this error when doing that :[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(no such table:  (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT [] FROM [] WHERE [] = "8d4eldkfjdfl58", (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)) sql 'SELECT [] FROM [] WHERE [] = "8d4eldkfjdfl58"' args []}

Comment: Database cannot find a table. Are you created table?

Comment: Name of database?

Comment: static final _databaseName = "MyDatabase.db";

Comment: You get error that starts with message `Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(no such table: (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR):`, check table name in query.